# want yaml file of Horizontal pod autoscaler for CPU and Memory metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, hpa

I got the command for hpa but it only for cpu metric.
I want to configure hpa for cpu as well as memory metrics

I tried editing hpa file and make changes there itself but failed.

then tried this yaml file but still got error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8B0j.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason.
In target section, Type must be there. it solved my error

apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
name: ph-prod-hpa
namespace: default
spec:
scaleTargetRef:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
name: ph-prod
minReplicas: 1
maxReplicas: 5
metrics:

- type: Resource
  resource:
  name: cpu
  target:
  type: Utilization
  averageUtilization: 70
- type: Resource
  resource:
  name: memory
  target:
  type: Utilization
  averageUtilization: 80

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).